# Rotation Group of a Soccer Ball

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am attempting to show that a soccer ball cannot have a 60 degree rotational symmetry through a line through the centers of two opposite hexagons. My proof so far:

If it had such a symmetry, let's call it Q, then the order of Q is 6. So then the stabilizer of a particular hexagon contains an element of order 6, which in turn implies the stabilizer must be of at least order 6 as well. Now, if I knew that the orbit of any hexagon is of order 12(which i know, but cannot seem to show), then this would mean by orbit-stabilizer theorem that the order of the entire group of rotations would be at least 72, which contradicts that the group is isomorphic to A<sub>5</sub>, which is of order 60.

How do I show the orbit of any hexagon is 12?

Comment: Not relevant to the specific question, but nonetheless of possible interest:  http://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2015/bridges2015-151.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetry group is $A_5$, which does not contain an element of order $6$.

Comment: I know I can do it like that, but i'm trying to explicitly use the orbit-stabilizer theorem...

Comment: Sir, please tell me how the order of group of rotations of soccer ball is computed? [ In case of regular icosahedron (a solid with 20 congruent traingles as faces) I just denote each traingle face from 1 to 20 and then uses orbit stabilizer theorem. From which I get $|G|= |orb_G(1)| |stab_G(1)| =20• 3=60$) ] But here(soccer ball)  there are  20 faces that regular hexagon and 12 faces that are regular pentagons. So how $|G|$ computed? Sir what to do of  that additional 12 pentagonal faces ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be easier just to observe that the six sides of one of the hexagons are not all equal -- three of them border on pentagons and three of them border on hexagons. So a 60° rotation like you describe would take pentagons to hexagons and vice versa -- it wouldn't be a symmetry at all.

Comment: I see that is easier. I am still curious though can you show that the orbit of a hexagon is 12?

Comment: @Paul: The orbit under which operation(s)? Under the full symmetry group every hexagon can move to any other hexagon, so the 20 hexagons form a single orbit.

Comment: orbit under any rotation I suppose? but no reflections.

Comment: @PaulMalinowski: By "under any rotation" do you mean under one arbitrary rotation, or under every rotation at once? Neither interpration seems to lead to 12 in any way.

Comment: under an arbitrary rotation